# Paragraph breaks using Stanford CoreNLP

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp

Is there a way to extract paragraph information from Stanford CoreNLP?  I'm currently using it to extract sentences from a document, but am also interested in identifying the paragraph structure of the document, which I'd ideally like CoreNLP to do for me.  I have paragraph breaks as double line breaks in my source document.  I've looked through CoreNLP's javadoc, and it seems there is a [`ParagraphAnnotation`](http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/edu/stanford/nlp/ling/CoreAnnotations.ParagraphsAnnotation.html) class, but the documentation doesn't seem to specify what it contains, and I see no example anywhere of how to use it.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

For reference, my current code does something like this:

```
    List<CoreMap> sentences = document.get(SentencesAnnotation.class);
    List<Sentence> convertedSentences = new ArrayList<> ();
    for (CoreMap sentence : sentences)
    {
        convertedSentences.add (new Sentence (sentence));
    }
```

where Sentence's constructor extracts the words from the sentence.  How would I extend this so that I get an extra level of data, that is my currently document-wide 'convertedSentences' list is supplemented by a 'convertedParagraphs' list, each entry of which contains a 'convertedSentences' list?

I tried the approach that seemed most obvious to me:

```
List<CoreMap> paragraphs = document.get(ParagraphsAnnotation.class);
for (CoreMap paragraph : paragraphs)
{
        List<CoreMap> sentences = paragraph.get(SentencesAnnotation.class);
        List<Sentence> convertedSentences = new ArrayList<> ();
        for (CoreMap sentence : sentences)
        {
            convertedSentences.add (new Sentence (sentence));
        }

        convertedParagraphs.add (new Paragraph (convertedSentences));
}
```

but this didn't work, so I guess I misunderstand something about how this is supposed to work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It appears that the existence of a `ParagraphsAnnotation` class in CoreNLP is a red herring - nothing actually uses this class (see http://grepcode.com/search/usages?type=type&id=repo1.maven.org%24maven2@edu.stanford.nlp%24stanford-corenlp@3.2.0@edu%24stanford%24nlp%24ling@CoreAnnotations.ParagraphsAnnotation&k=u - quite literally, there are no references to this class other than its definition).  Therefore, I have to break the paragraphs myself.

The key to this is to notice that each sentence contained within the `SentencesAnnotation` contains a `CharacterOffsetBeginAnnotation`.  My code then becomes something like this:

```
    List<CoreMap> sentences = document.get(SentencesAnnotation.class);
    List<Sentence> convertedSentences = new ArrayList<> ();
    for (CoreMap sentence : sentences)
    {
        int sentenceOffsetStart = sentence.get (CharacterOffsetBeginAnnotation.class);
        if (sentenceOffsetStart > 1 && text.substring (sentenceOffsetStart - 2, sentenceOffsetStart).equals("\n\n") && !convertedSentences.isEmpty ())
        {
            Paragraph current = new Paragraph (convertedSentences);
            paragraphs.add (current);
            convertedSentences = new ArrayList<> ();
        }           
        convertedSentences.add (new Sentence (sentence));
    }
    Paragraph current = new Paragraph (convertedSentences);
    paragraphs.add (current);
```

Comment: I see what you are trying to do, but I am not able to figure out imports. What is the package for Paragraph?

Comment: @user1211 it's been a while since I looked at this, but I believe `Paragraph ` was one of my own classes that simply contained the list of sentences.

Answer (score 0):

I would implement this by recognizing paragraphs with regular expressions, which if you defined them with double line breaks should be no problem. Then you can implement Paragraphs as either an own class with just one field (an ArrayList with the sentences in the paragraph) or just simply use a list of sentences for representing a paragraph.

Comment: Sure, I can split the paragraphs with a regular expression, but how do I then correlate this to the sentences returned by CoreNLP?  So, let's say I have a `List<Sentence>`, each of which is an object containing a `CoreMap` object returned by CoreNLP.  I also, due to having split the paragraphs by regex, have a `List<String>` which contains each original paragraph from the document.  For each `Sentence` in the list, how do I work out which paragraph contains it?  I can't pass the paragraphs to CoreNLP separately, because then it won't be able to resolve references between them correctly.